# rails new fails with 'couldn't set additional authenticated data' on macos

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos-monterey

I'm trying to get ruby on rails working on a new Mac with an M1 chip. Running `rails new` fails after `append .gitignore` with the following error

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:173:in `auth_data=': couldn't set additional authenticated data (OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError)
```

- MacOS version: 12.3.1 Monterey, Chip: Apple M1 Max
- Ruby version: 2.6.8p205 (2021-07-07 revision 67951) [universal.arm64e-darwin21]
- Rails version: 6.0.3
- Node version: 14.19.0
- Yarn version: 1.22.18

Has anyone else run into this? My rage-googling hasn't come up with much of anything on this one

Comment: Instead of using system ruby, I would suggest using rbenv to install gem to avoid version conflicts. Then you can use
`export RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)"` to set the correct SSL version

Comment: Interesting... Based on your advice, I set the local ruby version to the installed 2.7.3 (instead of system's 2.6.something, I believe), and then the `rails new` command succeeded.. Since you gave me the idea, do you want to write up an answer and I'll mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using system ruby, I would suggest using rbenv to install gems to avoid version conflicts. Then you can use `export RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)"` to set the correct SSL version

Comment: sorry, newbie here: how do I use `rbenv` to install gems? I'm using `rbvenv` to install Ruby 3.1.2 and this is still failing, even after running the export that you posted

Comment: @noloman what error do you get when installing Ruby?

Comment: sorry for the delay: what I did was uninstalling Ruby and installing it again and it worked - sort of "have you tried turning the computer off andd on again?" :)