# `auth_data=': couldn't set additional authenticated data (OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

trying to create a new project on RoR and i get this error:

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.6.1/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:170:in `auth_data=': couldn't set additional authenticated data (OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.6.1/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:170:in `_encrypt'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.6.1/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:148:in `encrypt_and_sign'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.6.1/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb:88:in `encrypt'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.6.1/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb:61:in `write'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.6.1/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:29:in `write'
    from /Users/carolinecagnin/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.1.6.1/lib/rails/generators/rails/credentials/credentials_generator.rb:30:in `add_credentials_file_silently'
    from /Users/carolinecagnin/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.1.6.1/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/app_generator.rb:194:in `credentials'
    from /Users/carolinecagnin/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.1.6.1/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:165:in `public_send'
    from /Users/carolinecagnin/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.1.6.1/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:165:in `build'
    from /Users/carolinecagnin/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.1.6.1/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/app_generator.rb:386:in `create_credentials'
    from /Users/carolinecagnin/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /Users/carolinecagnin/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    from /Users/carolinecagnin/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:134:in `block in invoke_all'
    from /Users/carolinecagnin/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:134:in `each'
    from /Users/carolinecagnin/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:134:in `map'
    from /Users/carolinecagnin/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:134:in `invoke_all'
    from /Users/carolinecagnin/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/group.rb:232:in `dispatch'
    from /Users/carolinecagnin/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/base.rb:485:in `start'
    from /Users/carolinecagnin/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.1.6.1/lib/rails/commands/application/application_command.rb:26:in `perform'
    from /Users/carolinecagnin/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /Users/carolinecagnin/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    from /Users/carolinecagnin/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    from /Users/carolinecagnin/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.1.6.1/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
    from /Users/carolinecagnin/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.1.6.1/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
    from /Users/carolinecagnin/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.1.6.1/lib/rails/cli.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:65:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:65:in `require'
    from /Users/carolinecagnin/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.1.6.1/exe/rails:10:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/bin/rails:22:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/rails:22:in `<main>'
```

Tried almost everything i found on internet and still can't solve it... I'm just trying to study lol I also use mac OS Monterey

Comment: Does this answer your question? [rails new fails with 'couldn't set additional authenticated data' on macos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71951610/895789)